# Can't use global variable in PHP

Tags: php, global

I'm trying to use a global variable, but it's saying that there's a unexpected equal sign? How is that...?

```
<?php

global $text = "text";
echo $text;

?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/chatwith/public_html/chatwithibot/test.php on line 3

Comment: Question about the `global` keyword. First thing to do: Google -> php.net -> manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global For further reference see: http://imgur.com/gallery/wOsEq7N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global is used to declare a variable, not define it.

```
global $text;
$text = "text";
echo $text;
```

I also urge you to look at the link Rizier123 provided about variable scope and work to reduce global usages.  Usually when you see the global keyword in PHP, it is a bad sign.

Comment: Just using it for testing purposes.